# How do i make a watch list in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to list out the table so that a new day, a new row next to each candidates. There shall be only for a given period. Some of you can help me with this?

```
create table shifts 
(
   shift_date date,
   doctor_name varchar(50),
   shift_fromtime date,
   shift_totime date
)
```

this is the way I want it to look like when i execute the query that I have not yet managed to write :)

```
shift_date   |   doctor_name   |   shift_time      |   shift_date   |   doctor_name   |   shift_fromtime 
01.01.2014    Peter                   07:00-15:00      02.01.2014    Nils                      07:00-15:00
01.01.2014    Nils                      14:00-22:00
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate columns in your query results?

Comment: It should represent the same table but with different dates. 
hope this brings clarity to the misunderstanding. :)